# Flutter Bloc - Register Handler issue

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout, bloc

I am looking for some help with my code. I want to create some swappable cards and for that I have created blocs. However, when I finished and tried to launch it, following message appears :

> Bad state: add(LoadMissionsEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
> Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  // final StreamChatClient client;
  // final Channel channel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
              create: (_) => SwipeBloc()
                ..add(LoadMissionsEvent(
                    missionDescriptions:
                        MissionDescription.missionsDescriptions)))
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "Student App",
          home: MissionChoice(),
          localizationsDelegates: [GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate],
          supportedLocales: [Locale('en'), Locale('fr')],
          // Scaffold(
          //   backgroundColor: d_green,
          // ),
        ));
  }
}
```